# VueJS: Why child component does not get rendered, when parent template in not x-template?

Tags: vuejs2

In the following code, when parent's template is an `text/x-template` as shown below, then child component (inside parent) **gets rendered** :

```
<script type="text/x-template id="#list">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>{{firstName}} - 
      <button @click="changeFirstName">Change</button>
    </p>
    <LastNameCmp></LastNameCmp>    
  </div>
</script>
```

however as shown below, if parent's template is derived from the html then child components does not get rendered. Why does that happen?

**template**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>{{firstName}} - 
      <button @click="changeFirstName">Change</button>
    </p>
    <LastNameCmp></LastNameCmp>    
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="item">
  <div><p>{{lastName}} - <button @click="changeLastName">Change</button></p></div>
</script>
```

**VueJS**

```
var LastNameCmp = {
  template: '#item',
  data() {
    return {
      lastName: 'Sharma'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLastName: function() {
      this.lastName = 'Abrahim'
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    LastNameCmp
  },
  data: {
        firstName: 'Rajat'
  },
  methods: {
    changeFirstName: function() {
      this.firstName = 'John'
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `LastNameCmp` to `last-name-cmp` or `lastnamecmp`
in your template like

```
<lastnamecmp></lastnamecmp>
```

- 

in Vue instance

```
components: {
   'lastnamecmp': LastNameCmp
}
```

Please see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html